# What exactly is pearinstaller?

Tags: pear

I see it in various places,but what's it for?

Comment: It's an installer. For pears.

Answer (score 2):

Not to be rude, but 2 seconds on Google would have answered this for you. It's the first hit. It's package management for PHP.

Comment: Part of the point of ServerFault (and the other StackOverflow sites) is to become a definitive source for answers - even those you can find with a quick google search. http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html

Comment: @MattB, does that mean this site should be the very first port of call for everything? As this site is intended for professional system admins it is more than reasonable to expect that at least some basic research has been undertaken before posting here. It's dross like this question that's making this site less and less useful.

Comment: From the link - "Every question in Stack Overflow is like the Wikipedia article for some extremely narrow, specific programming question." This is so simple a question, it does seem like it doesn't fit the mission of the site.

Comment: This is all excellent discussion, but better suited for meta stackoverflow. (Specifically: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-deal-with-google-questions) I think the general consensus is if you don't like the question ignore it (or even downvote it) but these types of questions should still have a place on SF.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the necessary documentation at http://pear.php.net/